# Android/Java: how to set background color of MaterialShapeDrawable with int Color?

Tags: java, android, textview

I have a TextView with rounded corners.

Here is my code:

```
float radius = 10f;
ShapeAppearanceModel shapeAppearanceModel = new ShapeAppearanceModel()
   .toBuilder()
   .setAllCorners(CornerFamily.ROUNDED,radius)
   .build();
    
MaterialShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = new MaterialShapeDrawable(shapeAppearanceModel);
    
ViewCompat.setBackground(textView,shapeDrawable);
```

Now, I want to change programmatically the background color of the textView.

When I do :

```
shapeDrawable.setFillColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(this,R.color.design_default_color_background));
```

it works; the background color is changed.

Now, I want to change the background color with an int color like Color.RED or any random color defined with  Color.RGB(r, g, b, a) or Color.RGB(r, g, b).

How can I do that? Should I use shapeDrawable.setFillColor or another method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**ANSWER to my question.**

Here is the code I added in order to be able to set any background color :

```
 int[][] states = new int[][] {
                new int[] { android.R.attr.state_hovered}, // hovered
        };

 int[] colors = new int[] {color};
 ColorStateList myColorList = new ColorStateList(states, colors);
 shapeDrawable.setFillColor(myColorList);
 shapeDrawable.setState(states[0]);
```

Crazy to have to write so much code just to change a background color...

Thanks all for your help !

Comment: Simpler kotlin version:

shapeDrawable.fillColor = ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.yourcolor))

Answer (score 1):

You can define global value for your color just like this

```
 public static final int RED = 0xffff0000;
```

And use like this.

```
 shapeDrawable.setFillColor(ContextCompat....(this, RED));
```

Comment: Thanks but gives : Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xffff0000 Any idea?

Comment: Try this int red = 0xff and after add color code, final int Red = 0xffff0000. I am not sure but try it.

Answer (score 0):

The method `setFillColor` works with a `ColorStateList`.
You can use something like:

```
int[][] states = new int[][] {
    new int[] { android.R.attr.state_focused}, // focused
    new int[] { android.R.attr.state_hovered}, // hovered
    new int[] { android.R.attr.state_enabled}, // enabled
    new int[] { }  // 
};

int[] colors = new int[] {
    Color.BLACK,
    Color.RED,
    Color....,
    Color....
};

ColorStateList myColorList = new ColorStateList(states, colors);
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use [setTint](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/shape/MaterialShapeDrawable#setTint(int)) method in your MaterialShapeDrawable like this:

```
val shape = MaterialShapeDrawable(shape)
shape.setTint(resources.getColor(R.color.colorPrimary, null))
```